# Using grepl() in a particular type of pattern matching

Tags: r

I'm not sure how to do this, I have a feeling that I can use `grepl()` with this but I am not sure how.

I have a column in my dataset where I have names like "Abbot", "Baron", "William", and hundreds of other names, and many blanks/missing-values.

I want to extract it in such a way where the first letter is extracted and put in a new column that only contains the letter, and if its missing a value then fill in with  unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Below I use a quick `sapply` statement and `strsplit` to grab the first letter. There is likely a better way to do this, but here's one solution. :)

```
test <- c('Abbot', 'Baron', 'William')
firstLetter <- sapply(test, function(x){unlist(strsplit(x,''))[1]})
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with

> and if its missing a value then fill in with unknown

?

The following code using `substr` should be very fast with a large number of rows. It always returns the first letter and returns `NA` if the respective value in `test$name` is `NA`.

```
test <- data.frame(name = c('Abbot', 'Baron', 'William', NA))
test$first.letter <- substr(test$name, 1, 1)
```

If you want to convert all `NA`in `test$first.letter` to `'unknown'` you can do this afterwards:

```
test$first.letter <- ifelse(is.na(test$first.letter), "unknown", test$first.letter)
```